# Does calling an 'external view' function in solidity broadcast a 'transaction' to the network?

Tags: ethereum, solidity

"In Ethereum, when you call a function on a contract, you broadcast it to a node or nodes on the network as a transaction." - [CryptoZombies (Solidity Tutorial)](https://cryptozombies.io)

Are there circumstances where function calls do not broadcast a transaction to the network?

How might one broadcast a transaction to a specific node?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Are there circumstances where function calls do not broadcast a transaction to the network?

Yes. `constant` functions are used for data retrieval from the blockchain that are *usually* run in the local EVM (they can be called from within a transaction as well). These calls are outside the scope of a transaction and you are not charged for the gas used to execute the call.

> How might one broadcast a transaction to a specific node?

You initiate a transaction by connecting to a specific node. This node can be local, or you can connect to a remote provider like Infura. However, once the transaction is submitted, it becomes a pending transaction across all nodes in the network and any miner on the blockchain can pick it up and process it. You can have more control over how transactions are processed by using a private blockchain.

Comment: Thank you.

"However, once the transaction is submitted, it becomes a pending transaction across all nodes in the network and any miner on the blockchain can pick it up and process it."

Do you happen to know whether it is possible for one miner to extend their mining algorithm to prioritize tx submissions from a specific node or tx submissions with certain metadata? 

i.e. 
App -> specific remote node -> pending tx.

Pending tx -> identified as priority by specific miner -> mines block immediately [though never makes it to the canonical chain].